# Create a static class function that takes an infinite number of arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that takes an arbitary number of strings and then outputs them all on a single line. I want this function to be a static member function of my Utils class.

```
Utils::output("I","am","a","sentence"); // --console-output--> I am a sentence
```

Here's what I've attempted:

***Utils.h:***

```
class Utils{
public:
    template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
    static void output(First arg, const Strings&... rest);
};
```

***Utils.cpp:***

```
void Utils::output() {
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Utils::output(First arg, const Strings&... rest){
    std::cout<<arg<<" ";
    outputs(rest...);
}
```

***main.cpp:***

```
int main() {
    Utils::output("I","am","a","sentence");
    return 0;
}
```

My project is currently not even compiling! I am getting this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Utils::output<char const *,char [3],char [2],char [9]>( referenced in function _main First.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```